# Game Loop simulation in Golang

Tags: go, goroutine, game-loop

I want to create game loop in go(lang), so i tried this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    // "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var v = 0
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var sec = 5

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    gameLoop()
    wg.Wait()
}

func gameLoop() {
    time.AfterFunc(16*time.Millisecond, gameLoop)
    v++
    fmt.Println(v)
    if v == sec*60 {
        // fmt.Println("Goroutines: ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        panic("err")
        wg.Done()
    }
}
```

This program running at 62.5Hz `(16*time.Millisecond)`, var `sec` is used for calling `wg.Done()` after 5 second and caused var `v` printed 300 times.

calling `panic("err")` making the result like this:

```
panic: err

goroutine 314 [running]:
panic(0x493c60, 0xc420094370)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
main.gameLoop()
    /home/billyzaelani/Desktop/main.go:26 +0x11f
created by time.goFunc
    /usr/local/go/src/time/sleep.go:154 +0x44
exit status 2
```

Well what is the meaning of `goroutine 314 [running]` ? did i use 314 goroutine for 5 second game loop? how if this run for hours?

But, if the program use runtime package and print `runtime.NumGoroutine` which is return number of goroutine, the result is `Goroutines:  2`

So, back again what is the meaning of `goroutine 314 [running]`? while runtime package say different things.

Last one, if anyone can show me the better way to create game loop in golang, i really appreciate that, thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AfterFunc` executes the registered function in a goroutine.  https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc

While there are only 2 go routines running at a time, there have been 314 (maybe?? Not sure how goroutine ids work) goroutines throughout the program.

---

i don't consider it a "better" way, but a different way, and my preferred, could be to model the game loop as a `for` loop.

```
func gameLoop()  {
    tick := time.Tick(16 * time.Millisecond)

    for {
        select {
        case <-tick:

        }
    }
}
```

In addition to concisely registering a case for an interval, selecting over a channel allows you to easily model a timeout, by adding another case for `<-time.After`, or for cancellation, by adding another case for a `<-done` channel.

Comment: it can even be written in a shorter way: `for range time.Tick(16 * time.Millisecond) { ... } `. And your suggestion is WAY better - more compact, more readable, less GC pressure, less context switches, and of course more idiomatic.

Comment: Well, i found this more elegant than `time.AfterFunc()`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is this like having a time step? Does this work for 30 frames per second?

Comment: @majidarif if you do the math, it could, yes - the answer here is based on 60fps (16ms * 60 ~= 1s).